# Upgrading MongoDB C++ Driver to mongocxx-3.1.2

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

How to upgrade from mongoDB C++ driver from Legacy to mongocxx-3.1.2 easly?
What are the classes in mongocxx-3.1.2 for following?

```
mongo::BSONElement;
mongo::BSONObj;
mongo::BSONObjBuilder;
```

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "upgrade" - the libraries offer entirely different APIs. You will need to re-write the parts of your application that interact with BSON or MongoDB in order to use it (you will also need a modern C++ toolchain).

To understand the analogues for the types you are asking about, I recommend reading https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/working-with-bson/

Complete documentation for the current stable version of the library (3.1.2) is available here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/current/

To elaborate a bit on the mappings of the types you requested:

- The closest analogue to `mongo::BSONElement` is `bsoncxx::document::element`
- The closest analogue to `mongo::BSONObj` is `bsoncxx::document::value` and its associated view type `bsoncxx::document::view`.
- The closest analogue to `mongo::BSONObjBuilder` is `bsoncxx::builder::basic::document`.